# How to schedule a Firebase Function every 1:30 hour but only start at 00:00 => (midnight)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to schedule a Firebase Function with Pubsub, the function will run every 90 minutes, But I need this function to run every day at midnight from the day start, so when I deploy the function it will not run until midnight, and then after 1:30 hour

I have tried so many ways but I couldn't find any straight answer to this operation.

```
functions.pubsub.schedule("every 90 minutes").timeZone('Asia/Riyadh').onRun(async () =>{

})
```

some of the options that I found online are using corntab but there is no straight way to achive this is what i have tried

```
functions.pubsub.schedule("0,59 0-23 * * *").timeZone('Asia/Riyadh').onRun(async () =>{

})
```

but this runs every hour or 59 min

`30 0-23/1 * * *`

this one also runs every 30 min past the hour which is not right or not what I'm looking for

I found this in [crontab page](https://crontab.guru/tips.html)

**tip**: More difficult schedules can be realized by combining multiple cron expressions. For example, if you need to run X every 90 minutes, create one crontab entry that runs X every 3 hours on the hour (0 */3 * * *), and a second crontab entry that runs X every 3 hours with an offset (30 1/3 * * *).

but I couldn't figure out how to wright it.

Answer (score 1):

> More difficult schedules can be realized by combining multiple cron
> expressions
> ...
> but I couldn't figure out how to wright it.

One approach is to create two Scheduled Cloud Functions that call the same code. Something along the following lines (skeleton):

```
exports.schedFunctions90 = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 90 minutes")
  .timeZone("Asia/Riyadh")
  .onRun(async () => {
    await schedFunctionLogic()
    return true;
  });

exports.schedFunctionsMidnight = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 0 * * *")
  .timeZone("Asia/Riyadh")
  .onRun(async () => {
    await schedFunctionLogic()
    return true;
  });

async function schedFunctionLogic() {
  //...
}
```

Comment: which one will run first mr. @Renaud Tarnec, I think every function will run
separately, what I intend to do is I need to run the function every 1:30 hour from the day start, even if I deployed the function right now it needs to start at 00:00 then 1:30 then 3:00 then 4:30 then 6:00 and so on

Comment: Yes the 2 CFs will run separately. If you need specific exact hours I would suggest to have a specific CF for each hour.